# Keeping Downstream API JWT Updated

Tags: .net-core, jwt

My .NET Core API calls a downstream API which is secured by JWT, obtained by `client_credentials` OAuth grant-type authentication. That JWT is only valid for one hour and needs to be refreshed. The downstream API is exposed internally in a singleton service and the service clients should not care about the token refresh.

A naïve implementation (which I currently have) is, that the service checks if the current JWT is valid  and if not, refreshes the JWT with the given credentials. That JWT is then cached for 3600 (or a little bite before) seconds and the same thing happens again.

This works well for a low "traffic" situations where there will be only one service call triggering this refresh. However, on high "traffic" scenarios this creates a bottleneck, where multiple requests will wait for that authentication to complete (or worse if I would allow this service to be used stateless and in parallel, that the JWT refresh is done multiple times).

I played around with a Background Service which refreshes the token on start-up and then on each interval (minus the grace time) and only exposes the actual token to the downstream API service. However this seems overly complicated which boils down to the actual question:

- What are best practices for refreshing time-bound downstream API keys?
- Are there any out of the box solutions in the .NET Core world for this? I've found `Microsoft.Identity.Web` but it only works around Azure (which is not possible in my case).

Comment: Check this: https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetcore/overview.html

Comment: Thank you very much @Artur, feel free to add this as an answer and I would award you the bounty. This is exactly what I was looking for and even after hours of googling I still missed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [IdentityModel.AspNetCore](https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetcore/overview.html)

```
services.AddAccessTokenManagement(options =>
    {
        options.Client.Clients.Add("identityserver", new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
        {
            Address = "https://demo.identityserver.io/connect/token",
            ClientId = "m2m.short",
            ClientSecret = "secret",
            Scope = "api" // optional
        });
    });

services.AddHttpClient<MyClient>(client =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://demo.identityserver.io/api/");
    })
    .AddClientAccessTokenHandler();
```